# play a livestream in ionic 4

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, http-live-streaming

i'm willing to create an app to monitor surveillence cameras, nothing fancy, just a simple android app that show my cameras flux in real time on the main page, and when i click on it it goes fullscreen. (app that i will later adapt to an android tv)
but i've searched for a way to play live streams via the "video" markup, but it didn't seems to work and i cant find any tutorial that fit my case :/

for now my app is just a simple html file that display mp4, so i dont have much code to show you

tldr: i'm looking for a simple way to play livestream videos in a ionic app (using the "video" HTML markup if possible)

Answer (score 3):

From some initial research there seems to be a bunch of examples out there but they are not for Ionic 4 (I was searching "ionic streaming media example").

There is an ionic 4 plugin for playing streaming media:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/

There are tutorials for ionic 3 like this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyS3uw7HZOM

Ionic 3 tutorials should show the core bits well enough for you to adapt them to Ionic 4, as long as you know how to build Ionic 4 apps.

If not, then you should probably spend some time learning Ionic 4 first but there is documentation about the changes between Ionic 3 and 4 (warning: there are a huge amount of changes to the component names and parameters, but the basic ideas are the same).

From the initial research though it seems you might have trouble getting the first requirement - playing the stream in a thumbnail in the main page. That will require some further research.

In my experience, videos load up full screen. There are tutorials that I have seen about playing the video preview but I think they are for local files and not sure how it would work attempting to stream multiple videos to your app. This would take a lot of bandwidth.

It would make more sense if you could have a thumbnail image snapshot from your camera that you can just update every minute or so.

Comment: Coincidence. I am currently working on an Application with live stream. and this plugin works fine for live streaming. it supports `rtsp` links.

Comment: hi harry, thx for your detailed response ! "uynfortunately" i already saw those tutorials, and they didn't worked for me... when the source is an mp4 file it works great, the thumbnail works and fullscreen when i click, but when i try with .m3u8 the thumbnail don't show and when i click on it the video dont show :/
i dont understand because every tutorial for "regular" html says .m3u8 format is ok as a source
moreover i'm looking for a "surveillance hub" look, with all the previews running at the same time...

Comment: rstp work in the plugin, but html dont recognize it

Comment: while we're at it, can you upvote this question ? idk why but it got instant -1 :(